# Windows server 2012 booting into cmd after .Net4.5 removal, DISM not helping

Tags: powershell, user-interface, cmd

Windows server 2012 booting into cmd after .Net4.5 removal, DISM not helping and I can not access PowerShell. I want to access the GUI again

Comment: You may want to post this to https://serverfault.com/ instead of SO since this is more of a server question than a scripting one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Powershell, you could try `Add-WindowsFeature Server-Gui-Shell, Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra`
(found that here: https://www.howtogeek.com/111967/how-to-turn-the-gui-off-and-on-in-windows-server-2012/)

There's also a technet blog https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/bruce_adamczak/2013/02/06/windows-2012-core-survival-guide-changing-the-gui-type/ that can help you

You may need to install Powershell first:
`dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell /all`

Comment: Thanks alot for the help.